# Calculate decay activity time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, radioactivity, subatomic

Given an initial nucleus, A, which decays to B and then B to C. I want to calculate the time when the radioactive decay activity of A and B are equal to one another. I have tried to set the $\lambda_A * N_A = \lambda_B * N_B$. But by doing that the time variable cancels out on both side. So what is the correct approach for this problem?

Comment: You don't show any time variable. How can they cancel?

Comment: Well, the activity is defined as  λN = λN_0*exp(-λ*t)

Comment: Only for A, and the $\lambda$ terms could be different. The expression for activity of B is more complicated because it has the decay of A feeding into the population of B while B decays: $\dot{B}=-\lambda_B N_B(t) + \lambda_A N_A(t)$.

Comment: If I set $B'$ = $A'$ then I would I end up with 0 = $−λ_BN_B(t)+2λ_AN_A(t)$. Move one of the product to the other side, then wouldn't t cancel out again? @BillN

Comment: No, don't do that. The activity of X is $\lambda_X X$, not $\dot{X}$.  You have to solve the $\dot{B} differential equation, which is non-homogeneous, and use the boundary condition for the general solution.  It's a non-trivial problem.

Comment: No. See the definition of activity in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you. So I solved for B by integrated $\dot{B}$. Now, can I set the activity to equal to one another?

Comment: @KaneBilliot since you solved it, might I recommend that you show the complete solution? It would turn this from a question "closed because of showing no effort" into one "worth upvoting because of the effort and complete solution"

Comment: @Floris the solution is added.

Answer (score 1):

Once I applied all the hints from Bill N (from the comment section), I arrived at the solution of $t = [ln(λ_A/λ_B)]/(λ_A-λ_B)$.

Comment: Glad you managed to add this before the question got closed... could you show the work (the solution is not as interesting as how you arrived at it).

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track--you want to solve that equation, just remember that $N_A(t)$ and $N_B(t)$ are functions of time (with $N_B(0)=0$).